# OnResponse body is null and return 500 error code

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit2

I have a request and response Json. When i submit the request then it will show response in my app. Url shows postman request and response [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW4jo.png I tried below code but the problem is facing that i got the correct JSONObject response but at the debug time when cursor goes in onResponse method of retrofit then body shows null and 500 error code. But in postman works everything fine.I lost 2 days with this problem.Please help me.

APIService

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/Conveyance/SubmitConveyanceRequest")
Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> saveTravelRequestDetails(@Body JSONObject submitRequest);
```

calling api

```
   public void btnOnClickSave() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_REIMBURSEMENT_HDR_ID, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_PROCESS_ID, 1);
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_INSTANCE_ID, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_REQUEST_NO, requestNo);
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_RAISED_BY, raisedBy.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_RAISED_DATE, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_APPROVER, selectedItemText);
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_APPROVER_DATE, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_TOTAL_AMOUNT, textViewTotal.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_STATUS, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_IS_DEVIATED, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_IS_DEVIATED_REASON, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_PENDING_WITH, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_RAISED_BY_NAME, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_APPROVED_BY_NAME, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_REMARK, remark.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_APPROVER_REMARK, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_PERFORMER, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_POSTING_CODE, "");
        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_STEP_ACTION, stepAction);

        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_DETAILS, getAddDetails());

        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_DOCUMENT_LIST, getFilePath());

        jsonObject.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_AUDITTRAIL, getAuditTrailDetails());


    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (Utility.getInstance().isNetworkConnected(getParent())) {

        Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> call = HDFCService.setSaveTravelRequestDetails().saveTravelRequestDetails(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelFileInsertID>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> modelInsertID, Response<List<ModelFileInsertID>> response) {

                AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                try {
                    List<ModelFileInsertID> insertIDs = response.body();
                    if (insertIDs.get(0).getIsSuccess() == true) {
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage(insertIDs.get(0).getMessage());
                        //progressBar.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        //  progressBar.dismiss();
                        mAlertDialog.setMessage(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.DATANOTSAVE);
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mAlertDialog.setTitle(AppConstants.AppText.HDFC);
                mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(AppConstants.AppText.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        getParent().clearBackStack();
                        //getParent().openHomeFragment();
                        //progressBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                mAlertDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), AppConstants.AppText.SERVICE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

public JSONArray getAddDetails() {
    JSONArray detailsArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    for (int i = 0; i < travelRequestAddDetailses.size(); i++) {

        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {

            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_REIMBURSEMENT_DTL_ID, 0);
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_REIMBURSEMENT_HDR_ID, 0);
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_DATE, travelRequestAddDetailses.get(i).getTravellingDate());
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_FROM, travelRequestAddDetailses.get(i).getTravellingFrom());
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_TO, travelRequestAddDetailses.get(i).getTravellingTo());
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_DESCRIPTION, travelRequestAddDetailses.get(i).getTravellingDesc());
            jsonObj.put(AppConstants.SaveKeyData.KEY_TRAVEL_AMOUNT, travelRequestAddDetailses.get(i).getTravellingAmount());
            detailsArray.put(jsonObj);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return detailsArray;
}
```

ModelFileInsertID pojo class

```
public class ModelFileInsertID {


@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("Request")
@Expose
private String request;
@SerializedName("IsSuccess")
@Expose
private Boolean isSuccess;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setRequest(String request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public Boolean getIsSuccess() {
    return isSuccess;
}

public void setIsSuccess(Boolean isSuccess) {
    this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
}}
```

Update

public class HDFCService {

```
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

private static final Retrofit RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AppConstants.AppText.SERVICE_BASE_URL).client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

private static final TravelRequestService TRAVEL_REQUEST_SERVICE = RETROFIT.create(TravelRequestService.class);

public static TravelRequestService setSaveTravelRequestDetails(){
    return TRAVEL_REQUEST_SERVICE;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you put the code where you call the request plz ?

Comment: @Fakher plz check

Comment: No i want to code in your activity where you call the request

Comment: this was i put already

Comment: Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> call = HDFCService.setSaveTravelRequestDetails().saveTravelRequestDetails(jsonObject);  in this line i got the request in jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the JSONObject as RequestBody

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject);
Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> call = HDFCService.setSaveTravelRequestDetails().saveTravelRequestDetails(requestBody);
```

API Service Interface:

```
@POST("api/Conveyance/SubmitConveyanceRequest")
Call<List<ModelFileInsertID>> saveTravelRequestDetails(@Body RequestBody body);
```

Comment: doesn't work, shows error No suitable method found for MediaType. Thanks for reply

Comment: You can include "compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'" in your app-level gradle , for that error.

Comment: it woks but my problem remains same

Comment: Pls check url once

Comment: yeah its correct the problem is that i got the correct url but that url doesn't get requestbody. body comes to null